# arm-none-eabi-binutils and arm-none-eabi-gcc versus binutils and gcc

Tags: macos, gcc

I find the arm-none-eabi-binutils and arm-none-eabi-gcc in the folder of /opt/local/var/macports/software

whereas normal binutils and gcc are found in the /usr/bin folder

what are the differences between the two?

when will the eabi-binutils and eabi-gcc be used?

are they targeting different architectures?

Comment: How did they get into `/opt/local/var/...`?  You must have installed them via a specific macport?

Comment: I just did port install arm-none-eabi-gcc
port install arm-none-eabi-binutils, not sure why into /opt/local/var/

Comment: OK, so *why* did you install those compilers?  (there is probably a front-end of some sort in `/opt/local/bin`).

Answer (score -1):

Those are cross-compilers installed by MacPorts for ARM (you must have run `port install arm-none-eabi-gcc` at some point). Unlike the normal `binutils` or `gcc`, which generate code for your computer, cross-compilers (and their associated tools in binutils) work with another architecture.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. if you enter,
`ll /usr/bin/gcc` you will notice that it will link symbolically to a file `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-9`. the sequence corresponds to the target machine the compiler was intended for (which is decided at the time gcc is built). You can refer to the gcc documentation for more information regarding this.

In this particular case, x86_64-linux-gnu is your target machine while arm-none-eabi will compile code for the arm architecture. Unless, you're developing for an arm based system like a micro-controller, I cannot realistically think of a situation where you would need it.